# Macro return value of type nullptr does not match function type

Tags: c++

I'm trying to do something like:

```
if (foo)
     return SET_ERROR_AND_RETURN_NULL(ERROR_HERE);
```

using...

```
#define SET_ERROR_AND_RETURN_NULL(error)
    lastError = error; \
    return nullptr;    \
```

so that later I can...

`if (GetMyLastError() == ERROR_HERE) { foo }`

However, I get `"Return value type does not match the function type."` Just defining SET_ERROR_AND_RETURN_NULL as a nullptr works of course, so I'm guessing it has to do with how types work with macros?

Perhaps I shouldn't do this using a macro, but I was inspired by windows system error codes. If it's a bad idea, I'd like to understand why a function call would be better.

I'm also trying to do it this way because I was hoping to keep the if statement return a one-liner without needing to set `lastError` there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A textual substitution shows the error.

```
if (foo)
  return SET_ERROR_AND_RETURN_NULL(ERROR_HERE);
```

becomes:

```
if (foo)
  return lastError = ERROR_HERE;
  return nullptr;
```

which is parsed as

```
if (foo)
  return lastError = ERROR_HERE;

return nullptr;
```

Now `return lastError = ERROR_HERE` will return the error (because of the return value of `=` operator), which is probably not the return type of your method. It's a macro, not a function so it's textually replaced: **if you return from a macro you are returning directly from the code in which the macro is expanded**.

That's why you shouldn't use them when you can avoid to use them, here a `static` method would have been enough.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. Figured something like that was happening but I was hoping I could still do it. Static function it is. Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't look like I can use "return SET_ERROR_AND_RETURN_NULL(ERROR_HERE)" despite it now being a function of type static void* and returning nullptr because the function I'm calling that in has a return type of something else. In the other words, the void* return type of my error function is not compatible with the function I'm trying to use it in, even though it's returning nullptr just like I'd be able to normally without using it.

Comment: That's because a `void*` can't be implicitly converted in another `T*` in C++. The best solution would be to have something like `template<typename T> T* SET_ERROR_AND_RETURN_NULL(ERROR_HERE) { lastError = ERROR_HERE; return nullptr; }` so that you can have it generic whenever you want, eg `return SET_ERROR_AND_RETURN_NULL<MyType>(ERROR_HERE)`